# Redirect from php to non php when request is comming from some other redirections

Tags: php, .htaccess

Searching in this same website I found the answer to redirect from http to https, from www to non-www and also from php to non-php on my url's. Codes that work perfectly ok, the final code is the next one:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
```

Now the thing is, everything was perfect, the thing is that SSL certificate and non-www version are recent changes, so I have indexed url's on the Google search like this one:

[darmon-avocat-divorce.fr/prestation-compensatoire/](https://www.darmon-avocat-divorce.fr/prestation-compensatoire/)

And when I click on that link I arrive on the nex url:

https://darmon-avocat-divorce.fr/prestation-compensatoire.php/

Then if I also manualy add some www like:

https://www.darmon-avocat-divorce.fr/prestation-compensatoire/

I also a arrive over:

https://darmon-avocat-divorce.fr/prestation-compensatoire.php/

So I'm trying to remove php extension when I'm comming from all other posible cases of redirection. Is this possible?